# setup.py install location?

Tags: python, macos, setuptools, distutils

I'm running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1 that has both python 2.6 and 2.7 installed. I've made 2.6 my default version. I am trying to install a package and it installs to 2.7. My setup looks like this:

```
~:hi› which python
/usr/bin/python

~:hi› python -V
Python 2.6.6

~:hi› python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6'
```

Shouldn't it be installed in 2.6 site-packages? Am I misunderstanding how this ought to work?

**Edit**

- The package in question is [virtuanenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/)
- I made 2.6 my default version like so:

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6
  ```
- I tried installing it like this:

  ```
  sudo python setup.py install
  sudo /usr/bin/python setup.py install
  ```

Comment: Which package? How did you install it? How did you make 2.6 the default? Please don't make us guess the crucial details.

Comment: Sorry about that... question edited to provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `setup.py` installs a Python package, it pays no attention to the Apple system settings. The only thing it knows is what version of Python you use to invoke it. If you say:

```
python2.6 setup.py …
```

then that version gets used, and the same with

```
python2.7 setup.py …
```

If you use the first of these two commands, does the package get installed under 2.6 like you want? My guess is that the shell that `sudo` runs might have 2.7 as its default, regardless of which Python your normal shell wants to use. What happens if you say:

```
sudo python -V
```

Comment: Yup, you nailed it. `sudo python -V` returned `Python 2.7.1`. I didn't realize that it could be different. Thanks a lot!